# Unable to import CSV file through Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, code-coverage

When I'm trying to upload the CSV file it.I have a custom object with having two fields name(text), salary (currency) for salary I got an Visualforce error and how to write the test class for that.

```
<apex:page controller="ClassDataEntryUsingCSV" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
 <apex:form >  
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:inputFile value="{!csvFile}"  fileName=" hellos"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Import Data" action="{!importData}"  />
                
    </apex:pageBlock>
    
    <apex:pageBlock id="abc">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!datalist}" var="data" >
            <apex:column value="{!data.Name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!data.Salary__c}" />
        
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>   
</apex:page>


public class ClassDataEntryUsingCSV 
{   
    public static blob csvFile{get;set;}
    public static String csvAsString{get;set;}
    public static string[] csvFileLines{get;set;}
    
    public static list<Raw_Data__c> datalist = new list<raw_data__c>();
    
    public static list<Raw_data__c> getdatalist(){
        return datalist;
    }
    
    
    public static void importData()
    {   datalist.clear();
        csvAsString = csvFile.toString();
        csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
        
        for(integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++)
        {
            raw_data__c obj = new raw_data__C();
             string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
            obj.name = csvRecordData[0];
           
            obj.Salary__c = Double.valueOf(string.valueOf(csvRecordData[1]));
            if(obj !=null)
            {
                datalist.add(obj);
            }
          }
        
        insert datalist;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same code but made few variations as per the objects I have in my org and I found that I was able to import the data using the same code can you check if the file you are using have proper values. Please find the csv file and the code I used below:

```
FirstName,LastName,Title,ReportsTo.Email,Birthdate,Description
Tom,Jones,Senior Director,buyer@salesforcesample.com,1940-06-07Z,"Self-described as ""the top"" branding guru on the West Coast"
Ian,Dury,Chief Imagineer,cto@salesforcesample.com,,"World-renowned expert in fuzzy logic design. 
Influential in technology purchases."
```

the above csv sample file is present in one of the topics of bulk API developer guide, here is the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_sample_file.htm).

The code I modified is for the account object.

Visual force page:

```
   <apex:page controller="Sample" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"> <apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock > 
    
    <apex:inputFile value="{!csvFile}" fileName=" hellos"/> 
    
    <apex:commandButton value="Import Data" action="{!importData}" />

</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock id="abc">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!datalist}" var="data" >
        <apex:column value="{!data.Name}" />
        <!--<apex:column value="{!data.Salary__c}" />-->
    
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class Sample {
public static blob csvFile{get;set;} 
    
    public static String csvAsString{get;set;} public static string[] csvFileLines{get;set;}

public static list<Account> datalist = new list<Account>();

public static list<Account> getdatalist(){
    return datalist;
}


public static void importData()
{   datalist.clear();
    csvAsString = csvFile.toString();
    csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n');
    
    for(integer i=0;i<csvFileLines.size();i++)
    {
        Account obj = new Account();
         string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
        obj.name = csvRecordData[0];
       
        //obj.Salary__c = Double.valueOf(string.valueOf(csvRecordData[1]));
        if(obj !=null)
        {
            datalist.add(obj);
        }
      }
    
    insert datalist;
    
}
}
```

Comment: Can you help me how to write the test class for that?

Comment: I have not written any test class as such but I was able to find a similar use case that used different code but this link [https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000005FyAIAU] had a test class that you could use for reference,but going forward I think it would be better if you could mention the errors you are facing after implementing or in case you have tried to implement but not able to do it you could mention the sources.